# Send value in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

Hi I was just wondering how to persist the data to another page. So far I've found out that I need a form to send it in, Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<form action="Result.html" method="get">
<textarea id="test" autofocus></textarea>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()"></button>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("test").value;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

This file that I'm using it's called Exercise1.html, I don't know if it helps or not but just in case it does. I know HTML, CSS, jQuery and Javscript so I rather prefer that

Comment: So use a submit button and submit the form, give the textarea a name.

Comment: You don't need a form, you arent posting the values anywhere.

Comment: to post form contents, [to another page, local file in your terms], you need to submit it to some server side code. For that, you need to write some code at the server side (ASP.NET, php, jsp, etc...)

Comment: Would you mind to send a code or something ? Because it's just that problem with the sending and displaying the value in another page that I don't really understand.

Comment: Do you mean with "page/local file" an other instance on the same computer or to other devices?

Comment: Yeah in the same computer

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_textarea_form You can google it :)

Answer (score 2):

Because loading a *new page* causes the JavaScript and HTML to be destroyed there is not way to preserve the value between page loads without some extra work. There are essentially three options.

#### Server Script

When the form sends data to a running server the server can take the value and inject it into the next page. Since this is a JavaScript question I will assume this is beyond the scope of the question.

#### Cookies / localStorage

Each page could look for a form of persistent storage on page load and populate the values. Usually you can save data to `localStorage` or possibly a cookie. Then on page load the JavaScript should load the value from storage and populate as needed.

#### Single Page App

In the case of a Single page app the value would be in memory and you manipulate the DOM to swap out *views* There are many frameworks that offer things like routing to make it look like a new page even though it is still the same page. Then you can populate values that way.

To explain in detail all options would be more then a single answer and more specific details should be searched and asked for.

Comment: I like this answer because it mentions localStorage which is far better than using cookies. Look it up.

Answer (score 1):

In the exercise1.html:

```
<form id="form1" action="result.html" method="get">
    <textarea id="aboutme" name="aboutme" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="bottom" name="submit" id="submit" value="Sign up" >
</form>
```

In the result.html:

```
<script>
var queryString = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
queryString = queryString.substring(1);
var queries = queryString.split("&");
for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; i++)
{
    var query = queries[i].split("=");
    document.write(query[1] + "<br>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is almost what I want it like but one question is there any possible way to remove the names of the textarea and the button ?

Comment: You mean not wanting to display the names on the result.html. You can split each query into name and value pair and print only the value see amended solution. If you do not want the submit button to be sent over, then remove the name attribute from the input type="submit".

Comment: I've just posted a code below and if you want to you can loook at it,,  I wan't it almost like that but I wan't to send the text to a specified page which in this case is Result.html and you know save the results there.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to persist your value to other pages on your webpage you can put the values in cookies:

```
// This saves your value
function saveField(){
    value = $('#test').val();
    document.cookie['myValue'] = value;
}

// This gets your value back on other pages
function loadField(){
    return document.cookie['myValue'];
}
```

More on how cookies work [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just wanted to say that I found another way to do display what key that was pressed, if anyone else is interested.

Javascript:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode,
   character = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
   console.log(charCode);

   if(e.charCode == 98 || e.keyCode == 98) {
      document.write("B = " + charCode + "<br>");
   } else if(e.charcode == 114 || e.keyCode == 114) {
      document.write("R = " + charCode + "<br>");
   }
};
```

So when you press B or R it displays the keyCode or charCode and it works in Chrome, Explorer and in Firefox (but it's a little slow in firefox, but it works).